# how to get params after using put method in RESTAPI

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im Using REST API and im using postman for webservice. After using put method i got this below array. How to i make this array as a normal array

```
Array(
    [------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "trackingNumber"

TestOrder_1234
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="advertiser"

Webservice
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="salesPerson"

sales person
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="publicationTitle"

publication title
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="adCategory"

Agricultural
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="specAd"

No
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="proofDate"

2016-04-25
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="runDate"

2016-04-25
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="publishDate"

2016-04-25
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pickupAd"

New Build
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requester"

shanthi05
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][product]"

Creative Products
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][prodcutType]"

Custom
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][widthColumns]"

10
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][depthLines]"

20
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][colorType]"

Full Color
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][artisticDiscretion]"

Full Artistic Discretion(AD3)
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][copyTranslationRequired]"

No
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="printSpecifications[1][creativeBriefInstructions]"

Sample instructions
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][product]"

Banners
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][outputType]"

GIF [Animated]
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][webOrderType]"

Rectangle
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][webWidth]"

180
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][webHeight]"

150
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][landingURL]"

www.test.com
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][artisticDiscretion]"

Full Artistic Discretion(AD3)
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webSpecifications[1][creativeBriefInsructions]"

Sample instructions
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="orderAction"

Submit
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deliveryDate"

Overnight
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="orderType"

Print
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[1][name]"

AW2023879_aw2015331_am_trader_ad_comple.pdf
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[1][fileSize]"

100
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[1][fileSpecificInstructions]"

trader changes template
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[1][ElementType]"

Graphic
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[1][url]"

S3 bucket relative path
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[2][name]"

file1.png
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[2][fileSize]"

100
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[2][fileSpecificInstructions]"

trader changes template
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[2][ElementType]"

Graphic
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[2][url]"

S3 bucket relative path
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="orderNumber"

4140787
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requestAction"

UPDATE_ORDER
------WebKitFormBoundary9F6kn9bF7EVHliR3--

)
```

and im using this code this preDispatch() method in zend framework

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $this->params);
    $GLOBALS["_{$method}"] = $this->params;
```

Comment: can I get url and relevant details ?

Comment: http://jdservices.localhost/orders/4140787 this is the url im using

Comment: :D your localhost url ? Okay. Once go through api documentation for clarification. This should not be the way to fetch the response